# Storybook webpack absolute import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, build, storybook

In our app we are using absolute paths for import modules. We have `react` folder into our resolve root:

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jup4.png)

We are using webpack for build and develop app and it works ok, with the next options:

```
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve('src')
    ]
  },
```

I'm working on integration of storybook and found, that it can't find any module from this `react` folder.

```
ERROR in ./stories/index.stories.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/components/Button' in 'project_name/stories'
 @ ./stories/index.stories.js
```

for the next line:
`import Button from 'react/components/Button';`

As mark: I added resolve/modules to .storybook/webpack config and also if I try to import anything other from, for example `services/xxx` - it works.

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

- `react` folder name conflicts with actual React package location: `node_modules/react`. Webpack tries to resolve to `.resolution`(default is `node_modules`) if the file does not exist in the path.
- `.resolution` is not appropriate for this sort of usage. it is mostly used for package resolution because it can't tell source strings.
- to change path selectively, use `alias` [instead](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias).

## Solution

1. change your component folder's name so that it does not collide with `node_modules/react`. a good example is `view/components/Button`.
2. add alias to `.storybook/main.js` setting

```js
// .storybook/main.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  /* ... other settings goes here ... */

  /**
   * @param {import('webpack').Configuration} config
   *  */
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    if (!config.resolve) config.resolve = {};
    // this config allows to resolve `view/...` as `src/view/...`
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
      view: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/view'),
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

3. change storybook code in accordance with (1)

```js
// Button.stories.jsx
import Button from 'view/components/Button';

//...
```

Comment: I don't have my code in `src`

Comment: @Shamoon does`.storybook/main.js` exist in a folder other than `src`?